# Storing multiselect form values in Mongo with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Below is my code which doesn't store anything into foods.ingredients array. Other fields (name, category) are stored correctly.

**Schema:**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    foods: [{
      name: String,
      category: String,
      ingredients: [String]
    }], 
    ingredients: [{
      name: String,
      category: String
    }]  
});
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/api/foods" method="post">
  Name
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <br />
  Category
  <select name="category">
    <option value="meat">meat</option>
    <option value="pasta">pasta</option>
    <option value="soup">soup</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  Ingredients
  <select multiple name="ingredients[]">
    <option value="beef meat">beef meat</option>
    <option value="potatoes">potatoes</option>
    <option value="onion">onion</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**api.js:**

```
var search = { 'username': "tester"};
var update = {
  $addToSet: {
    foods: {
      name: req.body.name, 
      category: req.body.category, 
      ingredients: { $each: req.body.ingredients }
    }
  }
}; 

User.findOneAndUpdate(search, update, function(err, food){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end('There was an error saving food.');
    } else {
      res.end('Food saved successfully!');
    };  
  });
```

Comment: AFAIK, You can't nest array operators in MongoDB currently. Why not just set the array directly (rather than using `$each`)?

Comment: It's something else about your code as I just recreated your app in a new express application and it at least worked OK. I don't know how you want this to handle updates ultimately, but the `$addToSet` is going to allow duplicate names/categories for the `foods` array.

Comment: @WiredPrairie storing array directly how you suggested works, thanks for the tip. Based on the official documentation on mongo site '$addToSet' won't allow duplicates : "The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array only if the value is not in the array already." Or am I misinterpreting this? Also, if array item is not a simple string but more complex object, how does mongo exactly determine if it's a duplicate or not?

Comment: If the new item is exactly the same, it shouldn't be added. But is that what you want?

Comment: `type: Schema.Types.Mixed` also we can use for mixed "anything goes" here [more details for mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)